# I need to encrypt my system drive and to boot it from password or usb keyfile not both but either

Tags: windows-10, usb, encryption, bootloader

Consider the following scenario:

I want to encrypt the Windows C: drive.

I also want to set a password and put an alternate bootloader or a keyfile on a USB so that when I start my pc and there is no usb plugged in, it will ask for a password and if the USB that has the alternate bootloader or keyfile is plugged in, it won't ask for the password and boot automatically.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's Bitlocker (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) is designed specifically for this, however you'd need Windows Vista or newer and either the Pro, Enterprise or Education version. VeraCrypt ("successor" to the popular TrueCrypt) provides full disk encryption as well and is free, although I do not know whether it supports a keyfile for this. (https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=System%20Encryption).

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Home. Which doesn't come with bitlocker, Can I install bitlocker on home edition, if not, can I upgrade home to pro edition without buying the full licence of pro edition. Also AFAK veracrypt does not support usb keyfile in new versions.

Comment: I suggest buying a key from a site like kinguin.net. The pro license will only cost you like $25.

Comment: Those keys are not authentic. Had one, stopped working in 6 months. Anyhow, I purchased it for $120 from windows upgrade directly from MS. The work I want to establish provides returns which can cover for the cost. The thing I wanted to do is working fine with windows 10 pro bitlocker. Thanx